# jQuery check CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fid: https://jsfiddle.net/79un7vw5/1/

I want to check if my div's background is red, on hover, move to the right.
Else, move div to the left on hover.

Why isn't it checking my css property correctly?

```js
$(".div").hover(function(){
if( $(".div").css('background') == 'red'){
$(this).animate({right: '0px', backgroundColor:"rgb( 20, 20, 20 )"});


    // will be called when the element finishes fading out
    // if selector matches multiple elements it will be called once for each
  }
  else{
  $(this).animate({left: '0px', backgroundColor:"rgb( 20, 20, 20 )"});

  }
  
});
```

```css
.div{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:absolute;
left:0;

}

.parent{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `if ($(".div").css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle for your issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/aw42aj2L/38/

And this is how the code looks like :

```
$(document).on("mousemove", ".div", function(){
if( $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
$(this).animate({right: '0px', "background-color":"rgb( 20, 20, 20 )"});


    // will be called when the element finishes fading out
    // if selector matches multiple elements it will be called once for each
  }
  else{
  $(this).css({"background-color": "#FFFFFF"});
  $(this).animate({left: '0px','background-color': "rgb(20,20,20)"}, 1200);

  }

});
```

And also, please notice the jquery UI being used here for color animation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```